# What effect does the handling stat have on weapons?

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

I have unlocked the Foregrip accessory now and it increases the handling of the rifles which I add it to.

What aspects of using a weapon are affected by this weapon stat?

Looking at the existing weapons, it seems that sniper rifles and light machine guns have low handling, especially with longer barrels. Yet submachine guns have higher handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Handling is greatly affected by the weight of the weapon, which in
>   turn affects its mobility. When using a heavier weapon, it will take
>   longer to stabilize the weapon after you point it in a different
>   direction, or aim down the sight. This also slightly affects your
>   movement and reload speed. Basically, you can shoot things faster with
>   a lighter weapon than with a heavy weapon. However, the advantage of a
>   heavier weapon is that it absorbs recoil better so is easier to
>   control under fully automatic fire. Even with a high Handling stat,
>   you’ll still need to make minor adjustments to your aiming while
>   firing to stay on target, but with practice this is almost a
>   non-issue. Just like weapons with low Accuracy, if the weapon that has
>   stolen your heart has bad Handling, try firing in bursts or single
>   shots to avoid difficulties.

From [here](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168639-tom-clancys-ghost-recon-wildlands/75087232)

tl:dr it affects recoil and aiming but it will not make shots more perfect when the stat is high

Comment: Cool, so it seems to be everything which isn't one of the other stats. I wonder how this interacts with the 'Time to aim' skill.

Comment: Makes sense. I think long barrels affect handling quite a bit. While short barrels improve it.  Bare in mind other stats will be affected too.